# Elegant way to only show records if they exist in rails ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm finding that I'm using a lot of repetitive code in my ERB views when displaying information about a user. Along the lines of

```
<% if @user.name.present? %>
  <%= @user.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'm basically doing this for everything in my view to avoid errors (e.g. older users who may not have all the new fields).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may inline the test `<%= @user.name if @user.name.present? %>` IIRC

Comment: `<%= @user.try :name %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move the logic into an helper :

```
def name_for(user)
 user.name if user.name.present?
end
```

And call that helper in your views :

```
<%= name_for(@user) %>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Note that calling `@user.name` on a user that doesn't have a name wouldn't generate an error. If `@user.name` was `nil` an error would only occur if you tried to call a further method on `nil` e.g. `@user.name.upcase`.

So if your condition doesn't enclose any other part of the view and you're happy to just leave a blank space if the user doesn't have a name you can just use `@user.name` without the `if` check.

You can also look at using `try` if you have a more complicated example. For example if users belong to a group, but some older users don't have a group you could display the group name with:

```
@user.group.try(:name)
```

`try` on `nil` just safely returns `nil` without an error.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/raganwald/andand

Use this to avoid these errors

user.andand.name

It will check if user object is nil then don't call name on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for this one :

```
<%= @user.name if @user.name.present? %>
```

But if you repeat the exact same things, the best way would be to create a def in your helper as [Florent pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106617/1805275).