# Ruby - ActiveRecord belongs_to and nil association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Imagine the following situation:

I have a user model and a user_group model, so:

```
Class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
end

Class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Now, let say some of the user does not have group. Which mean, when I call:

```
<% @u.each do |item| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= item.id %></td>
                <td><%= item.username %></td>
                <td><%= item.name %></td>
                <td><%= item.user_group.name %></td>
              </tr>
              <% end %>
```

It will throw nil. Is there any way nil will be displayed as empty string (somewhat like LEFT JOIN, or DataMapper include_related in CodeIgniter) instead of showing error page?

Right now I am using

```
<%= item.user_group.name unless item.user_group.nil? %>
```

to check before calling, but doing that for all view file is somewhat not a good approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `delegate` for this. http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: I did play aroud with delegate, but not quite able to make it work. Care to explain with examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to only show records if they exist in rails ERB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106500/elegant-way-to-only-show-records-if-they-exist-in-rails-erb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)..

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
  def contact
    "Manufacturer has been contacted." 
  end 
end

Product.first.try(:manufacturer).try(:contact)
 #=> nil 
Product.last.try(:manufacturer).try(:contact) 
#=> "Manufacturer has been contacted."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an helper too:

```
def group_name_for(item)
 item.user_group.name unless item.user_group.nil?
end
```

And call that helper in your views:

```
<%= group_name_for(item) %>
```