# Best way to deal with an error caused by a method returning no values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is implemented to read in values and fill in a table with the appropriate values, however when one of the methods doesn't return anything it produces an error and crashes the page.

```
<tr class="event-row" >
  <td><%= event.description %></td>
  <td><%= event.contact.name %></td>
  <td><%= event.start.strftime('%H:%M') %></td>
  <td><%= event.end.strftime('%H:%M') %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_event_path(event) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "delete", event, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are       you sure?"} %>
  <td><%= link_to "show", event_path(event) %></td>
</tr>
```

How can you check to see if the methods are returning no values?

Comment: you can say `event.try(:description)` `event.try(:contact).name` `event.try(:start)` `event.try(:end)`. this will not throw the error

Comment: Or use the andand gem which I think reads slightly better. Or use a presenter that knows what to do, that's probably better yet.

Comment: @cockmagic- yes bcoz `event.try(:contact)` is nil and we are calling `name` on that that's why. you can try `event.try(:contact).try(:name)` or see my answer. using if conditions also you can achive this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to only show records if they exist in rails ERB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106500/elegant-way-to-only-show-records-if-they-exist-in-rails-erb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also check if that value is present with if

```
<tr class="event-row" >
  <td><%= event.description %></td>
  <td><%= event.contact.name if event.contact %></td>
  <td><%= event.start.strftime('%H:%M') if event.start %></td>
  <td><%= event.end.strftime('%H:%M') if event.end %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_event_path(event) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "delete", event, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are       you sure?"} %>
  <td><%= link_to "show", event_path(event) %></td>
</tr>
```

You can use try 
Try will returns nil rather than raising an exception

```
event.try(:description) 
event.try(:contact).try(:name) 
event.try(:start) 
event.try(:end)
```

For more clarification, have a look at this

[try public method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

Comment: And move that new logic into helper.

Comment: @FlorentFerry It is good idea to move the logic into helper, if user want to use same thing number of times, to support DRY priciple

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try(:name)` or **delegate** with `allow_nil`:

add this to your `event` **model**:

```
 delegate :name, to: :contact, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

and this in your **view**:

```
<td><%= event.contact_name %></td>
```